# Poor CMS blog vs Tumblr embed

Tags: seo, blog, tumblr

A client of ours has a basic blog that is built into their CMS - its simply a header / image / text field that is updated regularly - the purposes of this is that the manager wants to add weight to the site - improve SEO and improve the knowledge that they have won a tripadvisor award for romance.

They have complained that their site doesn't allow them to tag articles at all and is too rigid for the purpose.  As I am not a .net developer (the CMS is built in .net) I figure the best way to improve the blog situation is to use a tumblr embed - which basically uses JavaScript to embed HTML into the page - and then style this too look like the existing blog - this would give them a complete - easily updated blog system with tagging - but I'm not sure whether this would be less beneficial for SEO? Can anyone advise please?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As a general rule, search engines don't read content created by JavaScript. There are some exceptions as this is changing over time, but the more complex the JavaScript is the less likely it is to be interpreted by search engines. This means your suggestion would not be beneficial for their SEO efforts.

If they're not satisfied with their current CMS they should consider changing to a CMS which has these features or hiring a .net developer to improve their existing one. If you want to be involved then you could contract that job out to someone but that's entirely up to you.

Comment: Just to add to that question John - as the current owner doesn't have the budget to hire another developer -  although not ideal as you say - will an external tumblr site which is fed into the site (via tumblrs JS / xml feed) have some SEO benefits - as it would also be an external feed in the tumblr community that links back to the site?  Else do you have any other suggestions!?  Thansk for your help.

Comment: To add to the above, would an external Tumblr blog with the domain URl blog.sitedomain.com pointing at it be a workable compromise - the blog could be external and also embedded into the existing site..  Cheers for your help!