# What are the SEO Benefits of adding a Tumblr feed to a website?

Tags: seo, blog, tumblr, feeds

A client of ours has a CMS driven Blog in his hotel site - he would like to use the blog to add depth top his site and add SEO benefits relating to the blogs content.

The current blog is a basic header / text field and doesn't contain any tagging / meta features.

Unfortunately we don't have a `.net` developer in our team to alter the existing blog and add meta / tagging and there isn't budget to hire one - so I considered using a Tumblr blog - setting it up externally - giving it a `blog.hotelname.com` address and feeding it into the existing page via Tumblrs JS - which basically does a document.write into the page - which we can style.

I understand from a previous post ([Poor CMS blog vs Tumblr embed](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49504/poor-cms-blog-vs-tumblr-embed)that) as a general rule most search engines ignore JS created content - but will the above approach act as an improvement on the existing system for now - as the blog will be setup externally with its own URL and also feed into the existing site?

Answer (score 1):

Simpy having a feed from tumblr will have no direct SEO effect what so ever on the site the feed is on (as the content wont be indexed as on the site). However if people liked content on the site that came from the feed, they may link to it and share it, so indirectly it may have some effect.

Also in connection with your other post, if the content did some how get indexed on your site (although most likely not as it's in JavaScript) you would then be looking at a the problem of duplicate content between your site and the Tumblr blog.

Is setting up a wordpress install not possible, this would be an easy solution I would have thought.

I hope I have understood your problem clearly.

Comment: Thanks moobot - if we setup a domain of blog.hotelname.com that points at the external tumblr blog - will that not tie in the seo benefit with the domain?  Else - yes I think WP is the way forward!

Comment: Do you mean making a sub domain on the main site with the tumblr feed on?

Comment: yes a sub domain on the main site (lets say its called hotel.com) which points at the tumblr hosted blog - so blog.hotel.com points at the tumblr blog but still ties in with the hotel.com domain - would that actually work?

Comment: This wont have any SEO benefit as mentioned in my main answer. The content isn't actually on the site, so there is no benefit to be had. My advise here would be installing wordpress on a subdomain, or sub folder.Then move all the content from the current basic blog over to the wordpress blog with all the tagging/meta options you require. This should be quite be easy to implement with simply a link pointing to the wordpress blog.

Comment: cool ok - cheers for your help moobot

Answer (score 0):

There will not any SEO benefit as stated in my main answer. The content is not actually on the site, so there is no benefit to be had. My guidance here would be installing WordPress on a subdomain, or sub folder. Then move all the content from the current basic blog over to the WordPress blog with all the tagging/Meta options you require.