# Is a Tumblr blog on my site good for SEO?

Tags: seo

I have a Tumblr blog on my "news" page on my website so if I keep this updated regularly will this improve my SEO and should I link it to my Facebook and Twitter?

Comment: Is the tumblr blog hosted on your site, or is it being fed from tumblr?  You might want to read this question: http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/49736/seo-benefits-of-adding-a-tumblr-feed-to-site/49739#49739

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, because next to blogspot and WordPress Tumblr is  one of the top blogging platform that always users to post and share everything. Your SEO will increase if you update it frequently. Link your blog to your Facebook and Twitter so that it would reach more people.

Answer (score 0):

Sure having Tumblr blog on your website will be always beneficial for increasing visitors you may also involve in tweeting your posting url's with anchor text. this will make your visitors redirected to your website. which will increase count of your visitors to your website.

Comment: How is this different/better than John's answer?